# Using subscript and line break at the same time in plot titles in R

Tags: r, plotmath

I wish to include a subscript and a title running into two lines at the same time but am not getting desired result with following commands:

```
base<-'B1'
compare<-'A1'
plot (1, 1, main = bquote('Annual mean' ~CO[2] ~'Flux Difference: \n'  ~.(compare)~ 'minus'~.(base)))
```

I wish to insert a line break after 'Flux Difference' but its not happening instead this term is hanging nowhere. Please help me.

Thanks,
Munish

Comment: Please put the command on separate lines and a dput of the head of your data.

Comment: @hd1: After you get some more cred you will be able to fix these newbie formatting lapses yourself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a fairly common request and there is no really clean answer. Plotmath will not accept a "\n" (and the help page documents this.) One dodge is to use each line as an argument to the plotmath function `atop`. The other plotmath trick sometimes of use is `phantom` with an empty argument list to allow the tilde not to throw an error, but that is not needed here:

```
plot (1, 1, main = bquote( atop('Annual mean' ~CO[2] ~'Flux Difference:' , 
                                     .(compare)~ 'minus'~.(base))) )
```

[image]