# printing text in multiple lines as the title of a plot or axis WITH a subscript present in the text

Tags: r

I wish to print a text in the title in two lines but am not able to achieve desired output because of subscript present in the text. Following is the e.g of the text that I want in two lines.

```
plot(1,main=expression(paste(CO[2]~'Flux (kg C ', m^-2,' ',s^-1,')')))
```

BUT using line break as in following command does not give desired result of bringing (only) the text following it in new line:

```
plot(1,main=expression(paste(CO[2]~'Flux \n(kg C ', m^-2,' ',s^-1,')')))
```

Please help me with this issue.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Didn't you ask this before and get the same answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13317428/using-subscript-and-line-break-at-the-same-time-in-plot-titles-in-r/13317495#13317495

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the `atop` function.

```
plot(1,main=expression(atop(CO[2]~'Flux', paste('(kg C ', m^-2,' ',s^-1,')'))))
```

[image]

Since the `lheight` `par` doesn't affect expressions, if you want tighter spacing between the lines, you can use the following.

```
plot(1,main=expression(textstyle(atop(CO[2]~'Flux', paste('(kg C ', m^-2,' ',s^-1,')')))), 
     cex.main=2)
```

[image]

Comment: it works well, any suggestion on decreasing (or increasing) the gap between the two lines?

Comment: @Munish the usual `par` value that would control this is `lheight`, but this doesn't have an affect on expressions. However, if in my answer you wrap the call to `atop` in `textstyle` and set `cex.main` to, say, 2 in the `plot` call, you'll get a tighter title of approximately the same size.

Comment: This answer just saved me hours of futile coding. Thanks!